# Azure roles for Blob storage for specific set of permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I need to grant AD users with minimum permission to do following activities using blob storage, what are the roles to be assigned.

1. Access to a storage account with read/write/delete permission on all containers and blobs underneath in Azure Portal
2. Ability to create SAS token.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and describe `Ability to create SAS token for creating external tables in azure data base pointing to the blob containers within the storage account.` in more details. 1st requirement is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @GauravMantri if the user can create sas token it should be ok, edit is done,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Access to a storage account with read/write/delete permission on all
> containers and blobs underneath in Azure Portal

For this [`Storage Blob Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor) role should be sufficient as it allows read/write/delete permissions to Blob storage resources.

> Ability to create SAS token.

For this [`Storage Blob Delegator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-delegator) will be needed.

For a list of Azure built-in roles for blobs, please see [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I noticed for user to navigate to blob storage in azure portal apart from blob contributor role, The Azure Resource Manager Reader role is also required is this correct?

Comment: Yes because listing storage accounts is not part of Azure Storage Data roles.